# When and how does re-rendering happens when stores emits any event in flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am a newbee in react + flux. I'm bit confused about when and how does re-rendering happens when an event is emmitted by stores. In my app I am listening to a event in the function componentWillMount() which is called just before rendering happpens. It's working fine and my views are getting updated. I have just once concern that what causing my component to re-render. 
Below is the codes.

**function to update store**

```
 createTodo(text){
const id = Date.now();
this.todos.push({
    id,
    text,
    complete:false
});

this.emit("change");
```

**My component -- listener method.**

```
componentWillMount(){

TodoStore.on("change", () => {
    this.setState({
        todos: TodoStore.getall()
    })
})
}
```

Here what is causing my component to re-render? Can you please explain me in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `setState` the component will re-render.

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

> setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: As I am calling setState in componentWillMount. The first time of rendering the component "setState" will be called just before rendering happens.  I am asking what will make componentWilMount be called again? I believe only that setState will be called again? Correct me pls

Comment: see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

So componentWillMount is called just once when component is mounting to DOM. If you have multiple same components then there will be multiple calls. TodoStore.on("change") is asynchronous (listener) so it won't change the state immediately. You could also try redux instead of flux..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call setState() in a react app it causes the state to render.
Basically every time state changes your render function inside your react component will get executed and your UI will be reflected of the new changes